# My register function only works sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a simple register function at my project which check for duplicate email in database.

```
protected void Reg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string em = email.Value;
    string id = nationalid.Value;
    string pass = password.Value;
    string country = DDLcountry.SelectedItem.Text;
    string dateof = dob.Value;

    string cid = ((id.Length > 9) ? id.Substring(id.Length - 9, 9) : id);
    string uid = DDLcountry.SelectedItem.Value + cid;

    string strpass = encryptpass(pass);
    SqlCommand chk = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE ([email] = @email)", con);
    chk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", em);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = chk.ExecuteReader();
    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        code = rand.Next(100001, 999999).ToString();
        sendCode();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into UserData(userID, email, country, nationalID, password, activatecode, DOB)values(@userID, @email, @country, @nationalID, @password, @code, @DOB)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", uid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", em);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationalID", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", strpass);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dateof);
        int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (j != 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ActivationEmail.aspx?em=" + email.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Registration Failed !! Try again !!')", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //user existed
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email Existed !! Try again !!')", true);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

**Problem**:

Even if I register, it sometimes does not work which prompt me an "email existed" message.
However, I'm using a brand **new email** which does **not exist** in database.

Comment: FYI http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ especially for your `AddWithValue("@DOB", dateof);` - is that a string or a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the `SqlDataReader`, you only need `SqlCommand` with `Execute.NonQuery()` and `Execute.Scalar`. The `Execute.Scalar()` will return one value, which you will use to count the rows, if the count is 0 then there is no record of that email, then you can use `Execute.NonQuery()` to insert the new email.

/*
        Count the rows instead. 
        Make sure you Trim and lowercase them both.
    */

```
// store the count 
int count = 0;
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserData WHERE LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM([email]))) = @email", connection ))
    {           
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", em.ToLower().Trim());
        connection.Open();              
        count = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); 
    }

// Check
if(count > 0)
{
    //user existed
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email Existed !! Try again !!')", true);  
}
else 
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString))
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into UserData(userID, email, country, nationalID, password, activatecode, DOB)values(@userID, @email, @country, @nationalID, @password, @code, @DOB)", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();  

            Random rand = new Random();
            code = rand.Next(100001, 999999).ToString();
            sendCode();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into UserData(userID, email, country, nationalID, password, activatecode, DOB)values(@userID, @email, @country, @nationalID, @password, @code, @DOB)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", uid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", em.ToLower().Trim()); //make sure to trim and lowercase it. 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationalID", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", strpass);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dateof);


            int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (j != 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("ActivationEmail.aspx?em=" + email.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Registration Failed !! Try again !!')", true);
            }

        }
}
```

`sendCode();` if it's regarding the inserted record, it will be best if you moved inside `if (j != 0)` so, if the record is inserted successfully, it'll send the code and redirect the user, but if is it meant to be used for verification (needs user input), then it should be before inserting the record.

also, you need to make use of `using` blocks, to dispose the connection automatically.

Comment: the line  using(var command = SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserData WHERE LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM([email]))) = @email", con)) have error non-invocable member sqlcommand cannot be used like a method

Comment: @Eason `var command = new SqlCommand(...)` forgot the `new` keyword.

Comment: I testing it and it have error also 
ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: @Eason it should work now, check the update.

Comment: it's still remain the same error.

Comment: @Eason oops, my bad, I forgot to replace the `con` in the SqlCommand to use the `connection`. try it now.

Comment: I still get the email existed if i use a new email to register...the solution does not work for me

Comment: @Eason check the `email.Value` it might be null or empty, where the `UserData` table has some records with null or empty `email`, which makes the count greater than 0.

Comment: I already set the email can't be null in database.

Comment: Depending on the collation of the column, you may not need to force everything to a specific case ("CI" in the collation means Case Insensitive) - saves a full table scan

Comment: @Eason review your code, use F11 on debug to execute your code line by line. I'm sure there is something you didn't see. Make sure of the email.value, and it's calling the correct method, and also, it's linked to the correct database.